# Grails/Hibernate max for string type

Tags: hibernate, grails

In my table I have a serial number field, which is represneted by string.. It has a prefix and some numbers follow. Eg: ABC1234, ABC2345 etc. How to retrieve the largest value (max equivalent of int type) from this column. In my case it would be ABC2345. I probably could retrieve all the data,, sort it and get the same, but that would be slow.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize [GORM criteria](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2%20Criteria), projections in particular:

```
def c = MyEntity.createCriteria()

def maxNumber = c.get {
    projections {
        max("serialNumber")
    }
}
```

This assumes that your entity is named `MyEntity` and field is named `serialNumber`.